# HTML, PHP, JavaScript -- How to make a button for each individual record in a database? Seems simple but doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysqli

I have an SQL database (I know for sure it includes remote access, if that's necessary to access a database through php). It definitely has at least one record in it, and I need to get each record and create a corresponding button that links to a php file, taking the first field for that record as a/n argument, variable, parameter, or whatever you call the whatever.php?variable=value.

For some reason, this code just gives me a blank page. Why?

```
<?php
    $connection=mysqli_connect("myhost","myusername","mypassword","mydatabase");
    $result=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM myTable");
    $resultArray=array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
        array_push($resultArray, $row['ID']);
    }
    $resultArrayImplode = implode(",", $resultArray);
?>
<script>
    var resultArray = <?php echo $resultArrayImplode; ?>
    arrayEntries = new Array();
    arrayEntries = resultArray.split(",");
    function CreateButtons(element, index, array) {
        var button = document.createElement("input");
        button.type = "button";
        button.value = element;
        button.onclick = function() {
            document.location.href = "ButtonClicked.php?id=" + element;
        }
        document.body.appendChild(button);
    }
    arrayEntries.forEach(CreateButtons);
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check the Javascript source code that is being output and read the browser's Javascript console errors.

Comment: I know I sound like an idiot, but exactly how would i go about doing that?  I think I get the part about reading the console errors, but do web pages even output source code?

Comment: Instead of using `implode` and `split`, you can just do `var arrayEntries = <?= json_encode($resultArray) ?>;`.

Comment: @DevinLynch99: Your browser's dev tools will show you the JavaScript/HTML source code of your page.  It's usually `F12` or `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`J`.

Comment: For your development, use FireFox and install the FireBug plugin. It will give you a javascript console and lots of other great tools.

Comment: @mvanlamz: I prefer Chrome's built-in tools, but Firebug's cool too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is `$resultArrayImplode;` is a string, so

```
var resultArray = <?php echo $resultArrayImplode; ?>
```

renders as:

```
var resultArray = 1,2,3,4,5
```

Which is a syntax error.

---

What you can do is use JSON.  JSON syntax is JavaScript syntax, so all you need to do is:

```
var arrayEntries = <?php echo json_encode($resultArray); ?>;
```

This should render as something like:

```
var arrayEntries = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

Which is perfect JavaScript syntax.  Then the rest of your code should work.

Comment: Ironically, I think the problem is that my browser doesn't like the first '<' in var arrayEntries = <?= json_encode($resultArray) ?>;

Comment: Because I tried doing what you said, and it still does the same thing.

Comment: @DevinLynch99: Your browser should have no idea that was ever a `<` there.  PHP is ran on the server, *well* before your browser ever sees the page.  PHP generates/renders the page, then sends it to the browser.

Comment: @DevinLynch99: What happens if you right click on the page and select "view-source", what do you see?  Can you see your JavaScript?  What if you press `F12` (or `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`J`)?  Do you see any errors?

Comment: Also, try `<?php echo` instead of `<?=`.

Comment: Well, I'm using chrome.  And when I do `F12` it shows my code, and that looks fine.  I click on `console` and then it says `unexpected token <` and I click on the link to the right of that error, and it points me to the line I just mentioned.

Comment: @DevinLynch99: And it's showing the `<?php echo json_encode($resultArray); ?>;` in your file?!  That means PHP isn't running.  It's either not installed, or your file isn't saved with `.php`.

Comment: yeah...The file is a .html, so you're saying I just need to change it to .php?  And will html still be parsed in a php file?

Comment: @DevinLynch99: HTML is parsed by the browser, not PHP.  But, yes, changing it from `.html` to `.php` should fix it.  PHP runs on the server and renders the HTML to send to the browser.  Anything not inside `<?php ?>` tags is just echoed to the screen normally.

Comment: Okay, well, It worked like you said....There is no php code in my `F12` thing, but, when I look at the javascript code, the array is empty!

Comment: @DevinLynch99: Well, time to debug the PHP code.  Make sure the SQL query works.  Make sure the query returned the rows you want, and make sure the array is being built.  [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) is your friend.

Comment: So you mean just trying to echo something if it works, and something if it doesn't?

Comment: @DevinLynch99: Pretty much.  That should help you figure out where the error is.

Comment: Thanks!  I mean for the javascript.  The PHP was entirely my fault.  I put in a 2 instead of a 3.

Comment: @DevinLynch99: So, you got it working?  Glad I could help :-D

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript assignment to resultArray is probably not syntactically correct due to quote characters, etc. Luckily, PHP's JSON functions automagically create good javascript for you.

Try this for the javascript output:

```
var arrayEntries = <?php echo json_encode($resultArray)?>;
```

Comment: Ironically, I think the problem is that my browser doesn't like the first '<' in `var arrayEntries = <?= json_encode($resultArray) ?>;`

Comment: Your browser shouldn't see the first '<'. The code inside '<?php ... ?>' is evaluated on the server.

Comment: For this to work i think you are missing the following:

$.getJSON('<?php echo json_encode($resultArray)?>;',fucntion(array){what you want to do goes here});

Comment: @Q_ro: `$.getJSON` runs an AJAX request.  It's not useful here.  You wanted `$.parseJSON`, which is also not useful here.  `<?php echo json_encode($resultArray)?>` will print JSON syntax which can be ran as JavaScript code without any parsing.  So `var arrayEntries = <?php echo json_encode($resultArray)?>;` is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

I just don't see why do you need to use javascript for this, cant you just do the following :

```
<?PHP
foreach($resultArray as $result)
{
?>
 <a href="ButtonClicked.php?id="<?PHP echo $result; ?>><div class="button">Im a button click me</div></a>
<?PHP
}
?>
```

in my opinion, i see no real need for you to use javascript for this.